# bigQuery assign a value to table 1 based on table 2

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to update Table 2 based based on Table 1 that is given by:

```
Row     sample_id   PIK3CA_features
1       huDBF9DD    chr3_3268035_CT  
2       huDBF9DD    chr3_3268043_AT  
3       huDBF9DD    chr3_3268049_T
```

Table 2:

```
Row     sample_id   chr3_3268035_CT  chr3_3268043_AT  chr3_3268049_C

1       huDBF9DD    1                1                null
2       huDBF9De    null             null             null
3       huDBF9Dw    null             null             null
```

For each row in Table 1, if its `samle_id` is correspondent in Table 2 then I'd like to update the respective `PIK3CA_feature` in Table 2 to 1.

How can I pass the `sample_id` and `PIK3CA_features` values from Table 1 as parameters to update Table 2 in a SQL command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`UPDATE` statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement) to accomplish this. Assuming I understand correctly, you want something like this query:

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE table2 AS t2
SET
  chr3_3268035_CT =
    IF(t1.PIK3CA_features = 'chr3_3268035_CT', 1, chr3_3268035_CT),
  chr3_3268043_AT =
    IF(t1.PIK3CA_features = 'chr3_3268043_AT', 1, chr3_3268043_AT),
  chr3_3268049_C =
    IF(t1.PIK3CA_features = 'chr3_3268049_C', 1, chr3_3268049_C)
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE true;
```

This will set the appropriate column in table 2 to have a value of 1 based on the value of `PIK3CA_features`. If you have a lot of these columns, you can generate the query using Python or some other programming language, or you can generate all the `column_name=expression` pairs using a query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(FORMAT('%s=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="%s",1,%s)',
                    PIK3CA_features, PIK3CA_features, PIK3CA_features), ',\n')
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT PIK3CA_features
  FROM table1
);
```

This produces a list like:

```
chr3_3268035_CT=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3268035_CT",1,chr3_3268035_CT),
chr3_3268049_C=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3268049_C",1,chr3_3268049_C),
chr3_3268043_AT=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3268043_AT",1,chr3_3268043_AT)
```

Comment: I tried that. the issue here that PIK3CA_features is not available at the target table to update (fires an error). At the target table to update, there are values like chr3_3268035_CT that available under PIK3CA_features at the input table. Any way to use these values for the update command?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Your question shows that table 1 has a `PIK3CA_features` column. If this is not correct, update your question to be more specific.

Comment: I want to update Table 2: Row     sample_id   chr3_3268035_CT  chr3_3268043_AT  chr3_3268049_C, Based on Table 1: Row     sample_id   PIK3CA_features. Maybe the order was confusing. thanks for the quick response

Comment: Ah, I think I understand better now. Can you see if this edit is what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks. that exactly what i want to do. I have 500 values for PIK3CA_features. is there a way to automate that?

Comment: I added an example of how you can generate the query.

Comment: thank you. thats look great! since the response to this query is a column (to be use with the update command), I will be limited to the size of the bigQuery column length. Do I avoid this restriction when I use python? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: For 500 columns you probably won't hit a limit on string lengths, for instance, but if you end up having thousands of columns at some point, you'll probably want to use e.g. Python instead to generate the query.

Comment: Thank you. I have thousands to work with in the future.

Comment: running this with 500 values returns the following error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element. when i tried with less values (by deleting part of them, the query run successfully. any advice what might be the reason. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea without seeing the query. If you can produce a small repro, you could post a separate question on StackOverflow.